# Copy node modules directory results in error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, file-permissions

I would like to copy all my `node_modules` to a subdirectory called `build`.
Here is what ive tried.

```
gulp.src(['node_modules/**/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('build/node_modules/'));
```

But this results in the following error.

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will copy all the folders and their files but not sub folders to do this, you have to specify base.

```
 gulp.src(src, {base:"."}).pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
```

In your case it will be

```
gulp.src(['node_modules/**/*'], {base:"."}).pipe(gulp.dest('build/node_modules/'));
```